# Element size relative to screen size in Watchkit

Tags: ios, objective-c, layout, watchkit

I'm currently making a WatchKit app that requires two different layouts based on some conditions. Because these two layouts are very similar (the one just has more elements than the other), I've decided to use the same interface controller for both (and because there's no way to programmatically determine which controller to load on startup).

However, the problem arises when it comes to the different screen sizes:

1. In my first layout I want the three elements to fill the screen on both sizes. To achieve this I used percentage values for their sizes, that always adds up to 100% (that way, there's no scrolling necessary on the 38mm and no empty space on the 42mm). 
   [image]
2. In the second layout, there are several more elements on the screen. So when I use the same percentage values for the same elements, they grow because the total size of the interface controller is bigger.
   [image]

What do you guys recommend I do to fix this problem?

**EDIT 1:**
Pictures are meant to represent what I want it to look like. Right now, the elements (like the map and button) are 30 and 40% of the interface controller size in both cases, making them huge on the second layout. I want them to maintain the same fixed size in both cases. However using a fixed number makes them either too big for the 38mm or too small for the 42mm.

**EDIT 2:** 
There seems to be a little confusion: When laying out elements on the Apple Watch, there are three options:

1. *Size to fit content* The element encloses all the elements within.
2. *Relative to container* You give it a percent value of the container.
3. *Fixed* You give it a value in points.

When I use the 2nd option, relative, I get a perfect output on both the 38mm and 42mm watch in the first layout. However, when adding more elements to the screen in the second layout, the size of the container increases, and so does the size of the elements.
When I use the 3rd option, fixed, I can get a perfect output on either one of the sizes. The elements are either too big for the 38mm, and scrolling is necessary even in the first layout. Or the elements are two small for the 42mm, and there's loads of open space.

I need a solution that will let the elements in the first layout fill the screen (such as with option 2), but won't increase the size of the elements in layout two (such as with option 3). There's no way to change this programmatically in WatchKit, so I need to come up with a third solution that would work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier to design the controller with absolute size values for both screen sizes?

Like size classes for iOS, InterfaceBuilder allows to switch between the watch sizes by clicking on the `+` icon:

[image]

where you can choose the watch size:

[image]

To see how the different layouts look you can change the preview on the bottom of the InterfaceBuilder window:

[image]

Comment: I didn't know you could set up custom sizes for the different Watch Sizes, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For situations like this in my own Watch app, I've created two separate groups, and I programmatically hide the one I don't want to be visible. That way, my code can decide which one to use in any given situation. It's not as nice as being able to resize elements, but it seems that it's the best we can do at the moment.

Comment: So using two map views in two individual groups, one in each?

Comment: Correct. Then, just hide/unhide the top-level container groups.

Comment: Ahh, clever. Not a very "pretty" solution, but as long as it works it's good with me haha. Thanks!

Comment: Agree that it's not very pretty. For what it's worth, it's also the way that a lot of devs are using to show full-screen messages (for example, if there's a "no data" or similar message to show).

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear exactly what the problem looks like. Without an example of exactly what is happening, and/or more detail on exactly how you are setting the current sizing, it is hard to be sure.

The best advice therefore that can be offered is to use the option that lets you set the sizing separately for 38mm and 42mm watches.

Comment: I don't know if you are familiar with developing for the Apple Watch, but all layout has to be done in Storyboards. When you choose an objects size, you can pick from three options: 1. Size to fit content, 2. Relative to container (in percentages), and 3. Fixed size (in points). My problem is that when using 2., the container grows large due to the added elements, and then this object (for example the map) grows larger. When using 3., it can only fit one of the two screen sizes perfectly - not both.

Comment: Modified to give the best advice possible without more information about what the problematic output looks like.